# Definition of limit convergence

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I want to show that the sequence represented by .9,  .99, .999, ...
converges to 1 but I'm unsure how to go about picking an epsilon such that it works

Comment: $9/(10^n)$ does not converge to $1$.

Comment: Did you mean $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{9}{10^n}\qquad\text{converges to }\;1\;\;\huge ?$$

Comment: Yes, I meant to say the sequence represented by xn := 9/(10^n)

Comment: Notice that the sequence defined by $x_n=\frac{9}{10^n}$ converges to $0$. In order to prove this let $\varepsilon >0$, by taking $N$ an integer number such that $\frac1{10^{N-1}}<\varepsilon$ we have. $$n\ge N\qquad\implies\qquad 0<\frac{9}{10^n}<\frac{10}{10^n}=\frac1{10^{n-1}}\le\frac1{10^{N-1}}<\varepsilon$$

Answer (score 2):

The sequence represented by $.9, .99, .999, \cdots $ can be written as the partial sums of the series $0.9\sum_{k=0}^\infty (0.1)^k$.  Then, the $n$'th term, $a_n$, of the sequence is given by

$$a_n=0.9\sum_{k=0}^n (0.1)^k=1-(0.1)^{n+1}$$

Now, given $\epsilon>0$, we have

$$|a_n-1|=(0.1)^{n+1}<\epsilon$$

whenever $n>-1-\frac{\log(\epsilon)}{\log(10)}$.  And we are done!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the sequence defined by $x_n=\frac{9}{10^n}$ converges to $0$. In order to prove this let $\varepsilon >0$, by taking $N$ an integer number such that $\frac1{10^{N-1}}<\varepsilon$ we have. $$n\ge N\qquad\implies\qquad 0<\frac{9}{10^n}<\frac{10}{10^n}=\frac1{10^{n-1}}\le\frac1{10^{N-1}}<\varepsilon$$

---

Now, the sequence $y_1=.9,\;y_2=.99,\;y_3=.999,\,\ldots$ given by $$y_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{9}{10^k}$$
converges to $1$, in order to show this let's take $\varepsilon>0$ and $N$ as above, then
$$n\ge N\qquad\implies\qquad|y_n-1|=\frac1{10^n}<\frac1{10^{N-1}}<\varepsilon$$

Comment: The question was changed after you answered it.